# How to pipe input with expect?

Tags: expect

I’m trying to test a program that reads some input on `STDIN`; require the user to make a choice with up and down arrows and press <kbd>enter</kbd>; then terminates.

However I can’t find a way to pipe text into the spawned program. The manpage doesn’t suggest anything for that.

I tried spawning a shell and piping content by hand but the program stills executes as if it weren’t in an `expect` script and asks me to make the choice myself.

Here is the code I tried. I generated it using `autoexpect` then modified it by hand:

```
set timeout 10
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000
send -- "echo \"my\\ninput\\nhere\"|myprogram\r"
send -- "\[B" # down arrow
send -- "\[M" # enter
expect -exact "input\r"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

I tried to modify it to directly spawn the program then pipe the input into `expect`:

```
set timeout 10
spawn myprogram
match_max 100000
send -- "\[B"
send -- "\[M"
expect -exact "input\r"
expect eof
```

But using `echo "my\ninput\nhere" | expect -f script.exp` doesn’t check anything and wait until the timeout is over.
I tested that by using `expect -exact "foobar"` which is something that can’t be outputted by the program: it doesn’t print any failure and at the end of the timeout exits with a `0` code.

Wrapping the program in a test script doesn’t work either because it detects it’s not running in an interactive shell and doesn’t show its UI:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "my\ninput\nhere" | myprogram
```

I should also say that I’m not the program’s author so I can’t modify it.

Update: If I remove the down key and follow @glennjackman’s instructions in the comments the following does work:

```
set timeout 10
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000
send -- "echo -e \"my\\ninput\\nhere\"|myprogram\r"
expect "Enter"
send -- "\r"
expect -exact "my\r"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: `echo "my\ninput\nhere"` does not add newlines. For bash you want `echo -e "my\ninput\nhere"` or portably `printf "%s\n" "my" "input" "here"`

Comment: After you `send` the (modified) "echo -e ... | myprogram\r", you need to `expect` something before you start sending more keystrokes. Is there a prompt or something to tell you to hit the down arrow?

Comment: @glennjackman Right, I have `shopt -s xpg_echo` in my `~/.bashrc` so I forgot about `-e`.

Comment: @glennjackman it’s not really a prompt; it’s a curses interface.

Comment: Yes but there must be some word(s) you can expect to see

Comment: @glennjackman I added `expect "Enter"` but I get the same result as before (it shows the interface then wait until the timeout is over).

Comment: Run your script with `expect -d` to see the verbose debugging output. You'll be able to see why your pattern is not matching.

Comment: @glennjackman Thank you for your help. It seems to be an issue with the down key. I removed it and now it works (see my update).